Fill a grid with numbers so that each row/column calculation yields the same number
Using all the integers 1 through 9, each exactly once, put a number into each square in the grid below so that the result of each row and column calculation is 5.
All operations are performed "left to right" or "top down".
Oh, wait!
You say there is no solution.  Okay, you can change some subtractions to additions (but no other changes).



Attribution:  Mostly Erich Friedman, partly me.

The beginnings of a solution: rot13(Fvapr gurer zhfg or na bqq ahzore bs bqq ahzoref ba rnpu ebj naq pbyhza, gurer zhfg rkvfg rknpgyl bar ebj jvgu guerr bqq ahzoref, naq bar pbyhza jvgu guerr bqq ahzoref.)

Based on other answers that already classified all solutions to the original puzzle, here is an observation that one can solve the puzzle with an additional constraint. Namely one can request that all intermediate results are positive and no negative numbers are needed. With this additional restriction one possible solution is given by

 
 2 + 4 - 1
 +   +   +
 6 + 8 - 9
 -   -   -
 3 + 7 - 5       

Unfortunately even with this additional constraint the solution is not unique.

There were several good answers to this puzzle but I decided to accept this answer because it is positively beautiful!

One possible solution is:

 

I found this by

 Trial and error, starting with the assumption that the answer would have a negative 9. The only equality that includes this has a positive 8 and 6 as the other two numbers. The only equalities that include a negative 8 are 7+6-8=5 and 9+4-8=5, both of which are use numbers that are already taken. Since 8 will be positive in both equalities it's in, I decided to put it in the top left corner, giving a top row of 8-9+6=5.

 From there, with the numbers we have left, there were only a handful of equalities starting with a positive 9, namely 9-7+3, 9-5+1, and 9-3-1. There were also only a few starting with a positive 8, namely 8-7+4, 8-5+2, 8-4+1, and 8-2-1 (with the second and third values in each potentially flipped). At this point, I chose two of those equalities that used different values, namely 8-7+4 and 9-5+1. With these chosen, it was just a case of filling out the last spots with the only values that would work. I don't know if I was just lucky it worked, or if there would have been more solutions.

I'm not sure

 If this is a unique solution, other than simple transformations. I know all the cells could be swapped on a diagonal for a second solution, and the last row/column can be swapped with either other row/column, for a total of 2*4*4=32 different transformations of this solution.


There are three essentially different solutions. The other two have 16 valid transformations each, for a total of 64 solutions.

@DanielMathias It would be great if you could post (as an answer) the other two solutions and talk a bit about the transformations you could apply to them.

It is possible to find a solution by hand using more logic and less bruteforcing/guessing.
First use Someone's insight:

 There are five odd and four even numbers to put in the grid. Note that every row and every column add to an odd number (if you flip the signs of negative numbers, then the sum increases by an even number, which is still odd). Since we need odd odds to get an odd sum, the only possible way to put the odd numbers is to fill a row and a column with odd numbers.

Also note the number 5:

 If we use a positive 5, we get the equation 5 (+-) x (+-) y = 5, which cannot be fulfilled when x and y are not equal. Therefore, 5 must be negative and be placed at the lower right side.

and the symmetry of the grid:

 Given any valid answer, we can swap the 2nd and 3rd column along with the signs attached on their left to get another valid answer. The same applies to the 2nd and 3rd rows.


 So it doesn't matter much if we choose to fill 2nd or 3rd row and 2nd or 3rd column with odd numbers. Since we need one of the column or row to have a place to put 5, let's just choose 3rd row and 3rd column.


e ? e ? o = 5
?   ?   ?
e ? e ? o = 5
?   ?   ?
o ? o ? o = 5
=   =   =
5   5   5

Make an educated guess:

 Let's assume the lower right corner is 9. Since two odds less than 9 that sum to 9 + 5 = 14 do not exist, the equations to solve become o ? o + 9 = 5, or o ? o = -4. The sign is obviously -, and we can pair up 1, 3, 5, 7 into (1, 5) and (3, 7) so that the two pairs have the difference of 4. Again by symmetry it doesn't matter where each pair goes.


e ? e ? 1 = 5
?   ?   -
e ? e - 5 = 5
?   ?   +
3 - 7 + 9 = 5
=   =   =
5   5   5

Now look at the first two rows:

 The 2nd row has e ? e - 5 = 5, which can only mean that the two es sum to 10. Then the other es (on the 1st row) also sum to 10. Since 6 ? 4 ? 1 or 4 ? 6 ? 1 cannot be made into 5, the 1st row contains 2 and 8, and the 2nd contains 4 and 6.


8 - 2 - 1 = 5
?   ?   -
e + e - 5 = 5
?   ?   +
3 - 7 + 9 = 5
=   =   =
5   5   5

And finally on the 1st column,

 The sign of 3 cannot be negative, since 8 - 3 is already 5 and we cannot add or subtract any number to get 5. So the column must be 8 - 6 + 3 = 5. The rest can be filled out without problems.


8 - 2 - 1 = 5
-   -   -
6 + 4 - 5 = 5
+   +   +
3 - 7 + 9 = 5
=   =   =
5   5   5


Nothing clever here, just a programmed evaluation of all permutations.
There are three essentially different solutions:

 
 2 - 1 + 4       3 - 6 + 8       4 - 6 + 7
 -   -   -       -   +   -       -   -   -
 3 - 5 + 7       7 - 4 + 2       8 + 2 - 5
 +   +   +       +   -   -       +   +   +
 6 - 9 + 8       9 - 5 + 1       9 - 1 - 3

Each of these can be manipulated through row/column swaps and/or reflection across the main diagonal to obtain groups of solutions. The first is equivalent to the solution found by DqwertyC and is in a group of 32 solutions. The other two produce groups of 16 solutions each, providing a total of 64 solutions.

If in your first solution we do the permutation that swaps rows 2 and 3 as well as columns 2 and 3 we get a solution so that all intermediate results are positive.

@quarague That’s cool!  I hope you post that as an answer.
